# Changing the font size of table using print.xtable

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I want to change the font size of the table using print.xtable.

Using

`print(xT, size="\\tiny")`

works but I don't know other options for size. Something like size="7pt" would be nice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may choose a particular font size with the `\fontsize{<size>}{<line space>}` command:

```
print(xt, size="\\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\\selectfont")
```

Comment: what are the options {9pt}{10pt} after fontsize

Comment: fontsize and line space

Comment: Using \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% for setting the table to 100% width size disables the options size="\\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\\selectfont".

What can I do to use fontsize{9pt}{10pt} but setting the table width to 100%?

Comment: @rcs This doesn't work for me. It outputs the desired .tex table file, but doesn't change the size or spacing. Does one of my options below disable the `size` option? `print(xtable(results), only.contents=TRUE, include.rownames=F, 
      include.colnames=T, floating=F,
      hline.after=NULL, size="\\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\\selectfont",
      file = '~/Dropbox/Paper/table.tex')`